# Why does Spring's Hazelcast4IndexSessionRepository implement deltas and a Hazelcast EntryProcessor?

Tags: hazelcast, spring-session

Spring-session provides a [Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/main/spring-session-hazelcast/hazelcast4/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/hazelcast/Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository.java) that stores the session data (represented as `MapSession`) in a Hazelcast cache. Instead of returning the MapSession directly from the repository, it uses its own wrapper class `HazelcastSession` (both MapSession and HazelcastSession implement the same Session interface). One of the reasons is for sure so that it can implement the different flush and save modes and support the update of the principal name index. But it also remembers all changes to the session as deltas and when the `save()` method on the respository is called, it uses an [Hazelcast4SessionUpdateEntryProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/main/spring-session-hazelcast/hazelcast4/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/hazelcast/Hazelcast4SessionUpdateEntryProcessor.java) to update the corresponding map entry of the Hazelcast IMap.

Why does the session repository not just set the MapSession object on the IMap directly via `put` without using an EntryProcessor? What is the benefit of the current implementation of recording the change deltas?

To my understanding of the [Hazelcast EntryProcessor documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/computing/entry-processor), an entry processor is useful when a map entry should be updated often without the client having to retrieve the existing value first. Instead of first getting the old value (which might require a network round-trip), the entry processor can be executed directly on the Hazelcast member that holds the data.

But in case of a Spring `Session`, the session data is loaded from the Hazelcast map at the beginning of each incoming web request anyway (or latest when the application code wants to read/modify the session content) and then held in local memory. All changes to the session during the processing of such a request are done to the local session object and it is then saved again to the Hazelcast cache when the request ends (or earlier depending on the flush/save mode). That means the saving can be done without executing an extra get request on the IMap first. So why not just call `map.put(MapSession)` instead of using an EntryProcessor to update only the attributes noted in the delta list?

The only explanation I could think of would be the attempt to minimize concurrent modification of the same attributes. By saving only the deltas in the EntryProcessor instead of storing the whole MapSession which was loaded earlier, the chance to overwrite an attribute value that was modified concurrently in a parallel process is less likely. But it is not zero. Especially if my application code stores and updates only the same couple of attributes in the session all the time, even with the EntryProcessor the update will not be safe because there is no optimistic lock scheme in place.

Thanks for the insight!

Comment: A session's `lastAccessedTime` is updated on every session access, and as a `long` it's only 8 bytes. A delta change is more efficient if that's all that changes in the session.

Comment: Also, you wouldn't expect concurrent modification to a session, as they would be associated with only the one user. Affinity routing on the browser assists here.

Comment: Hi @NeilStevenson, could you please point me to some more info about browsers doing affinity routing? I couldn't find anything useful with a web search. I found the following discussion regard the Redis Spring session store where a user seems to have exactly the problem of concurrent updates of the same session: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/1471 So I guess it can happen for any backing store.

Comment: @NeilStevenson regarding the more efficient update: even an EntryProcessor has to set/put the modified data object on the IMap in the end because it only retrieves a clone of the currently stored data. I assume that Hazelcast is agnostic to the actual content and therefore still needs to serialize (if not using Object format) the whole object (and also distribute it to all backup partitions). So how is this so much more efficient that it justifies the additional complexity of recording deltas? Thanks!

Comment: See [sticky-session[(https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-wm#using-sticky-sessions).